# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier within ajax handler

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm getting mentioned error with code like:

```
var request = {
    action: "coupg_subscribe_affiliate", 
    email: $('#affiliate_signup_email').val()
}
$.ajax({
    type: "post", 
    dataType: "json", 
    url: coupg_ajax_object.ajax_url, 
    data: request, 
    success: function (e) {
        if (e.status == 1) {
            window.location = e.link;
        }
        else if (e.status == -1) {
            alert('Unknown error has occured. Please notify administrator as soon as possible.\nError code: ' + e.error);
        }
    }
})
```

I have exactly same code for AJAX somewhere else and it works. Here, it gives me mentioned error. Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: What is the format of the JSON being returned? It sounds like the jQuery deserialiser is throwing an exception because the response not formatted correctly.

Comment: Exception is thrown out right after page is loaded,  before request is even sent.

Comment: Which line is causing the problem?

Comment: You need a semicolon after for your JSON object. var request = { ... }; Sometimes it can cause problems when you leave it out.

Comment: Okay, this was exactly semicolon after request. Write an answer so I can accept that please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the semicolon after your JSON object.

```
var request = {
action: "coupg_subscribe_affiliate", 
email: $('#affiliate_signup_email').val()
};
```

Best,
aj